# How to print in file array

Tags: java, arrays, file

Soo, I have to insert list of arrays into a specific text document.
The array list is inset by user at case 1 and it works well.
When I try call case 4 without any data, the file is created and also it's empty.
When I do this with an array list I get the Error message from catch.
How can I fix it?

Here is the call to function.

```
case 4: System.out.println("\nLungimea dintre doua orase alaturate\n");
                try{
                    System.out.println("oabdobasoda");
                    salvareOras();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Eroare");
                }
```

and here is the function.

```
public static void salvareOras() 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<drum.size()-1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; i<drum.size(); j++){
                if(drum.get(i).getPozitie() > drum.get(j).getPozitie()){
                    Oras aux = drum.get(i);
                    drum.add(i, drum.get(j));
                    drum.add(j, aux);
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream("distante.txt");
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fOut);

            for(int i = 0; i <drum.size()-1; i++){
                ps.println("d(" + drum.get(i).getNume()+","+drum.get(i+1).getNume()+")="+distOras(drum.get(i), drum.get(i+1)));
            }
            ps.close();
            fOut.close();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Nu s-a putut crea fisierul");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's easier to debug when you print out the exception. It might give you a clue what's wrong.

Comment: People seem to [keep messing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062767/dealing-7-random-non-repeating-cards-out-of-a-deck-of-52/30062840#30062840) up with this `i` and `j` and `k` stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a minor mistake in your 2nd for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<drum.size()-1; i++){

    //specifically on this line here:
    for(int j = 0; i<drum.size(); j++){
                 //^//That is not j

        if(drum.get(i).getPozitie() > drum.get(j).getPozitie()){
                                  //that means ^ will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException
            Oras aux = drum.get(i);
            drum.add(i, drum.get(j));
            drum.add(j, aux);
        }
    }
}
```

Just change it to:

```
for(int i = 0; i<drum.size()-1; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<drum.size(); j++){
                 //^ j
        if(drum.get(i).getPozitie() > drum.get(j).getPozitie()){
            Oras aux = drum.get(i);
            drum.add(i, drum.get(j));
            drum.add(j, aux);
        }
    }
}
```